# Display custom post type taxonomy and month

Tags: custom-post-types

I have created events as custom post types and I'm storing the event start date as a custom field (`YYYY-mm-dd`). I've also assigned a taxonomy to each event.

I need to display a list of events by category in a single month.

The code below shows that I am currently able to display a list of events by the taxonomy `'bmx racing'` but I now need to display all the bmx racing events in any given month.

I need to work out how to take the month from the event start date (custom field) and apply it to this query.

```
<?php
query_posts( array(
'post_type' => 'event',
'event-category' => 'bmx racing'
'posts_per_page' => '-1', 
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
     ) );
  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?>

  <h3 style="color:#99cc00;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
  <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Any help is much much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there anyone that can help with this, I'm still struggling to display custom posts types within a date range.

Answer (score 1):

Do a simple `meta_query` and compare by `meta_value_num`.

```
array(
    'post_type' => 'webcast',
    'meta_key'  => 'webcast-date',
    'meta_value'    => array( time(), strtotime('+60 days') ),
    'meta_type'     => 'numeric',
    'meta_compare'  => 'BETWEEN',
    'orderby '  => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'     => 'ASC'
);
```

For an easy example. You can find more complex examples on the site filed under [meta-query](/questions/tagged/meta-query) - even more if you combine that with a [search for »meta_value_num date«](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmeta-query%5D+meta_value_num+date).